# Cognos framework join issue

Tags: entity-framework, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8, cognos-tm1

I have  a issue in cognos framework, here is the below explaination for the same.
I have a two tables.
1. SMRDLRD
2. F_SVC_HSTRY

DEALER table contains a dim column for dealer code keys.
SERVICE HISTORY table contains 2 dim columns for delaer code keys. (1st dim for service dealer codes and 2nd dim is for repair dealer code.. here,one service dealer code have many repair dealer code)

And now I have a requirement where I have to perform below join
SMRDLRD.I_DLR_DIM = F_SVC_HSTRY.I_CURR_FLET_DIM
AND
SMRDLRD.I_DLR_DIM = F_SVC_HSTRY.I_CURR_REP_DIM

But here I m not able to join one dim column on both the dim columns of other table.
However I had tried creating alias of a SMRDLRD table ,but the catch is SMRDLRD has so many other reference /lookup tables(say LKUP_CNTRY, LKUP_DOM etc ).
And that is where I m not able to bring all this tables into the picture.

Any help would highly appreciate.
Please let me know in the comment section if you need more information on this.
Thank you.

Comment: Please folks reply back ASAP.

Comment: That should work fine, but that join will result in this filter:  F_SVC_HSTRY.I_CURR_FLET_DIM = F_SVC_HSTRY.I_CURR_REP_DIM.  Are you sure that reporting only on records where the REP and FLET values match is the requirement?

Comment: Hi dougp, let say I have a fleet code 00011 which has several repair dealer assign to it like  45162,34352 etc you can say rep dim is the lowest grain and feet dim is upper grain but smedlrd table contains both this grain details within the one column only.. and since the package is going to use for adhoc reporting, I m not getting how users gonna use this fileds. And in cognos fm it is very difficult to apply a kind of join of two fact cloumns on one dim column